Failed to parse URL when building nextjs client in api platform
I've been trying to play around with API platform these last few days. However I must be missing something. When I follow the steps in "getting started with...", to generate the nextjs client, everything seems to work: I can go to localhost/greetings and I can add, edit and delete greetings.
However, after that I tried to follow https://api-platform.com/docs/deployment/minikube/. This fails in the build step of the pwa with the error

TypeError: Failed to parse URL from undefined/greetings.

This is the same error I get when following the steps to build a nextjs client here: Here it says to go to localhost:3000/greetings after starting the server with pnpm dev. Going to that page gives me the same error as I wrote above. After this, the page that originally worked (localhost/greetings) does not work anymore, I can access it, but it keeps refreshing constantly.
So I don't understand why there seem to be two ways to create and access the nexjs client. And secondly... what can I do to prevent that error?
I have tried following the whole "getting started"-guide, creating the books and reviews classes, but that gave even more problems, as I had to remove the references to reviews in the books template and vice versa, because those caused errors. So I tried with just the Greeting class, to be sure it wasn't any of my alterations that caused the problems.
I also had to leave out the --target option in the build steps, because of "target stage could not be found" errors. So possibly that's the cause of the error during building, but I have no idea which valid targets I should then configure.
I have been doubting my sanity, because in every step I try to copy from the api platform docs, some error pops up, while I try to follow the instructions to the letter.
